# A count is returning NULL when it should just be zero

Tags: mysql

I have a table that tracks users trustworthiness.

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
| user_id_1       | user_id_2       | is_trusted  |
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------+
| 1               | 2               | 0           |
...
```

Where 1 is trusted and 0 is not. If there is no negative feedback I get NULL for the value. Is there a way to just get the positive - 0?

```
select tr2.user_id_2 user,
    ((select count(*) plus
        from trust_ratings tr
        where is_trusted = 1 and
        tr2.user_id_2 = tr.user_id_2
        group by tr.user_id_2)
    -
    (select count(*) minus
        from trust_ratings tr
        where is_trusted = 0 and
        tr2.user_id_2 = tr.user_id_2
        group by tr.user_id_2)) as score
    from trust_ratings tr2
    group by user;
```

Comment: did you try each query individually?

Comment: Yes and they give the correct numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `case when`:

```
select   user_id_2 user,
         sum(case is_trusted when 1 then 1 else -1 end) as score
   from  trust_ratings
group by user;
```

Or:

```
select   user_id_2 user,
         sum(is_trusted * 2 - 1) as score
   from  trust_ratings
group by user;
```

Comment: That just adds up the trusts but I want to subtract the distrusts from the trusts give a overall trust

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that. Updated my answer using `sum` and `else -1`. I would not use 2 subqueries, which makes the engine access the table 3 times.

Comment: Added an even shorter version.

Comment: Can you explain to me that bottom one? I haven't tried it but it seems like it would just count the trusted users.

Comment: If *is_trusted* is 0, then we have 0 * 2 - 1 = -1. When *is_trusted* is 1, then we have 1 * 2 - 1 = 1. It is important however, that *is_trusted* really is 0 in the negative cases, not `null`. If you use `null` for that, then the first solution is the better one.

Answer (score 1):

Use `COALESCE()`:

```
select tr2.user_id_2 user,
    (
        coalesce(
        (select count(*) plus
        from trust_ratings tr
        where is_trusted = 1 and
        tr2.user_id_2 = tr.user_id_2
        group by tr.user_id_2), 0)
    -
        coalesce(
        (select count(*) minus
        from trust_ratings tr
        where is_trusted = 0 and
        tr2.user_id_2 = tr.user_id_2
        group by tr.user_id_2), 0)
    ) as score
    from trust_ratings tr2
    group by user;
```